# Crimes of Grindelwald: There is a book in the cabin where Credence was

Tags: harry-potter, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

When Leta switches the babies during the sinking ship scene in Crimes of Grindelwald, we can briefly see a book on a bed next to the crib. It has some sort of a symbol on it.

[image]

Can anyone make out that symbol? Is it present somewhere in other movies? Can it tell anything about Credence family?

Comment: @Valorum I don't think so, the one in the ship has round edges. Check it on YT to get more than one image. https://youtu.be/9_Hc7_s_cuE?t=94

Comment: @Valorum Sorry, I wasn't clear. I am talking about the symbol, not the book. (I am not sure how to call these top/bottom/left/right edges of the symbol properly clear in English to TBH)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's a Holy Bible, [embossed](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/59245fd09f7456571bff3e92/1495675524783-NX7EBFMG6WFQB682ETTX/BDB_Schuyer_Quentel_NKJV_SchuylerCross.png?format=1500w) with a [Jerusalem Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_cross) on the cover, with [gilt edging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4a0yYgfPPE&t=260s).

[image]

[image]